# jquery string value not getting passed into google map object inside loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, jquery-gmap3

Why is the string lost inside the object within a loop?

```
for (var i = 0; i < nrow.length - 1; i++) {
displayNote = "<b>" + nfield[0] + "</b><br />" + nfield[1] + " " + nfield[2] + "<br /> " + nfield[7];
$('#googleMap').gmap3({
    action: 'addMarker',
    lat: parseFloat(nfield[5]),
    lng: parseFloat(nfield[6]),
    events: {
        mouseover: function (marker, event) {
            var map = $(this).gmap3('get'),
            infowindow = $(this).gmap3({ action: 'get', name: 'infowindow' });
            if (infowindow) {
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
                infowindow.setContent(displayNote);
```

displayNote only displays the first increment for all the other infowindow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at the end of for loop execution displayNote will contain last value. And InfoWindow will show last displayNote on mouseover. 
You can save displayNote for each iteration by creating new function

```
function attachEvent( displayNote, nfield ){
  $('#googleMap').gmap3({
    action: 'addMarker',
    lat: parseFloat(nfield[5]),
    lng: parseFloat(nfield[6]),
    events: {
        mouseover: function (marker, event) {
            var map = $(this).gmap3('get'),
            infowindow = $(this).gmap3({ action: 'get', name: 'infowindow' });
            if (infowindow) {
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
                infowindow.setContent(displayNote);



}


for (var i = 0; i < nrow.length - 1; i++) {
displayNote = "<b>" + nfield[0] + "</b><br />" + nfield[1] + " " + nfield[2] + "<br /> " + nfield[7];
attachEvent( displayNote, nfield  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, problem solved. But from what you are saying the for looped finished before the googleMap object is parsed therefore only the last value retains despite it being within my loop?

Comment: @paranoidx function you provided on mouseover will get called after for loop finish, in your code it will use last value.